# Sample industry standard Java (Java EE, Java SE or Spring) application source code

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

Where can I download or view industry sample standard Java application source code for learn the coding standards and coding styles? Java EE or Spring based application would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first recommend you to go through [coding conventions by Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). You could then look at the standards that are following for its own API (Collections, ThreadLocal, java.util classes). `src.zip` located at `$JAVA_HOME` of the installation for accessing the sourcecode (IDEs should generally resolve it).

If you like to look at more, try other popular opensource frameworks like [Spring](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework), [Hibernate](https://github.com/hibernate) and popular [apache](http://www.apache.org/) projects like lucene, camel etc

Also, it would be a nice practice to use [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) and [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to improve the quality of the code you write.

Hope this helps